# learning about arrays, trying to implement postfix conversion to result

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following postfix to convert:

```
outputArray = [3,4,*,2,9,3,/,4,/,6]
```

Wanted result is `slicedArray = [3, * , 4 ]` so I can perform arithmetic operation.

This was my approach which did fail for some reason...

```js
let outputArray = ['3','4','*','2','9','3','/','4','/','6']

outputArray.forEach((element) => {
  while ((
      element !== '*' ||
      element !== '+' ||
      element !== '-' ||
      element !== '/' ||
      element !== '^'
    )) {
    resultArray.push(outputArray.shift(element));
    console.log("Hi Panda " + resultArray)
  }

  if (element.includes("+") ||
    element.includes("-") ||
    element.includes("*") ||
    element.includes("/") ||
    element.includes("^")) {
    let panda = resultArray.length;
    resultArray.splice(panda - 1, 0, element)
    let slicedArray = resultArray.slice(-3)
    console.log(slicedArray);
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you explain how `[3,4,*,2,9,3,/,4,/,6]` is supposed to yield `[3,*,4]`? What did your code output?

Comment: Please do click "Run code snippet" and fix the obvious errors that show up (like the fact that `outputArray` is not defined). Also, the `outputArray` you have above is invalid, because strings are not quoted.

Comment: @user1599011 Sure.  You scan the array from left to right ...in this case start from 3 go to 4 and when you reach an operator ..*..in this case...you splice the operator and slice the last three outputArray elements...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have updated the outputArray and let resultArray= [ ];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a stack and push all value until you got an operator, then add a new array with left and reich value and the operator.

```js
const
    operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'],
    data = [3, 4, '*', 2, 9, 3, '/', 4, '/', 6],
    stack = [];
    
for (const value of data) {
    if (operators.includes(value)) {
        const
            b = stack.pop(),
            a = stack.pop();
        stack.push([a, value, b]);
        continue;
    }
    stack.push(value);
}

console.log(stack);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

An approach to get the value.

```js
const
    operators = { '+': (a, b) => a + b, '-': (a, b) => a - b, '*': (a, b) => a * b, '/': (a, b) => a / b },
    data = [3, 4, '*', 2, 9, 3, '/', 4, '/', 6],
    stack = [];
    
for (const value of data) {
    if (value in operators) {
        const
            b = stack.pop(),
            a = stack.pop();
        stack.push(operators[value](a, b));
        continue;
    }
    stack.push(value);
}

console.log(stack);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I would be happy if I could implement the above using pure array.

Comment: what do you mean with pure array? do you want to get the results?

Comment: I thought stacks and arrays were two different DS.

Comment: javascript has no stack data type.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have answered all my questions properly.

Comment: Hey still working on it. Everything is perfect but I found a NaN error when the postfix has two consecutive operators.  For exambple when your data is   data = [3, 4, '*','+', 2, 9, 3, '/', 4, '/', 6],

Comment: the data is not valid, because you have no second value to add.

Comment: I don't mean to bore you but I wanted the second value to be the evaluation of the 3*4 which is 12 ..and replace the 3*4 with 12 and move on like  data=  [12,'+',9,3, '/', 4, '/', 6]